# Can someone explain the difference between ~(으)ㄹ 정도로 and ~만큼?

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, both can be used in the ~는 것 construction. However, despite having searched about these topics, I still have trouble differentiating between them. Can someone explain cases where one would be more acceptable, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

정도, 만큼 : describing a size, volume or level

This is so long it could be recorded as a world record.

이것은 세계 기록으로 기록될 정도로 (만큼) 길다.

He is so smart he could go to Harvard.

하버드에 갈 만큼(정도로) 똑똑하다.

@ They have almost the same usage, but 정도 (degree) can be used to explain
a fixed point or area in our tacit consent.

Our patience has a limit.

참는 것도 정도가 있다.

But 만큼 needs that additional clause or phrase in the sentence.

Comment: reference : http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000227816&supid=kku000289586